# In scala List :: doesn't do implicit conversion

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

In scala, it is OK to convert a variable in the `Seq`, but if I construct the `Seq` with `::` it doesn't work.
For example

```
  case class A(s: String)
  implicit def toA(s: String): A = A(s)

  val Seq(a, b, c, d): Seq[A] = Seq("a", "b", "c", "d") // compiles
  val Seq(e, f): Seq[A] = "e" :: "f" :: Nil             // won't compile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Seq("a","b","c","d")` is actually `Seq.apply[X]("a","b","c","d")` where `X` is inferred to be the `A` from the left hand side. And in `Seq.apply[A](...` elements of type `A` are expected, so strings are implicitly converted to `A`s via `toA` (so it's actually `val Seq(a, b, c, d): Seq[A] = Seq.apply[A](A("a"), A("b"), A("c"), A("d"))`).

But `"e" :: "f" :: Nil` is actually `::[Y]("e", ::[Z]("f", Nil))` where firstly `Z` is inferred to be `>: String` and secondly `Y` is inferred to be `>: String` so it's of a type `>: List[String]` (actually `List[Serializable]`) and it doesn't match type pattern `Seq[A]`. So there is compile error.

Basically the thing is you have an implicit conversion from `String` to `A` but not from `Seq[String]` to `Seq[A]`.

If you write just `val Seq(e,f) = "e" :: "f" :: Nil` then this compiles since right hand side matches pattern in the left hand side.

Also `val Seq(f): Seq[A] = "f" :: Nil` compiles since in `::[Z]("f", Nil)` there is only one type parameter and it can be inferred to equal `A`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is no reason for the compiler to apply the implicit conversion until too late. The expression

```
"e" :: "f" :: Nil
```

creates a `List[String]` which is incompatible with `Seq[A]` which causes the error.

To fix this you would need to have an implicit conversion from `List[String]` to `List[A]`.

Note that this **doesn't work** either:

```
"e" :: "f" :: List[A]()
```

You can add a `String` to a `List[A]` so it won't implicitly convert to `A` for you, and you end up with `List[Serializable]`.